# Eclipse not preserving permissions when copying files to output folder

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment

I have a Java Project with source folder configured to output to a war/WEB-INF/classes folder. Eclipse will output my class files into this folder with the correct permission (i.e. those set in Properties > Resource > Permissions). However, any non-class files get copied to the default output folder with only read/write permissions for the owner.

This is kind of annoying. Eclipse does not seem to respect the Permission settings for these files. I haven't found an option yet to enable Eclipse to preserve the file permissions. Is there such an option, or do I have to do this manually?

Motivation: I run eclipse as my own user, and also run a tomcat instance as apache. Apache is running with Jrebel, and Jrebel needs to scan specific class-paths in my code-base for changes. If the permissions are wrong, Jrebel cannot do this.

Comment: More information please , as to wht kind of project it is and also are the classes being copied with ant script?